# PL/SQL. Is it possible to use SELECT INTO from table dual?

Tags: plsql

Is it possible to use SELECT INTO from the dual table like this?

```
SELECT * INTO myTable
FROM ('val1' COLUMN1, 'val2' COLUMN2 FROM dual) dualTable
```

I would use this, because I need to insert values and get them back in a same statement.

Comment: It is possible; just add SELECT, here: `... from (select 'val1 column1, ...`. On the other hands, it depends on what myTable is. Furthermore, I don't understand what you meant to say by "need to insert values" (insert *where*?) "and get them back" (back *where*?) "in the same statement". Perhaps you should rather describe a **problem** you're trying to solve, instead of suggesting an answer which - apparently - didn't work as you'd want it to.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much to it other than just making two variables.

Below is the code

```
SELECT 
  'val1' COLUMN1, 'val2' COLUMN2 
INTO
  variable1, variable2
FROM 
  DUAL
```

Regarding the insertion part, I don't think it's possible to be done in the same statement. You can always write a procedure in the back to handle this.

Comment: "Keep in mind that with INTO you can not handle multiple rows. Only one." >>> Not really. It stands for *scalar* variables, but - what prevents you from inserting INTO a collection?

Comment: Fixed the reply. Sure you can insert into a collection, but seeing that they are using dual, it's very unlikely they want to get more than 1 row in the first place.